# Allign the tinymce floating panel to the right

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce 4.4.1 in inline mode. I want the `floatingpanel` on the right side like in [this demo](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/).

But even if I download this demo to my server, the floatingpanel appears on the left side.

Where could I adjust that?

Here is the code snippet I cutted together to fit on one page from the example above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="content">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inline Mode</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://www.tinymce.com/css/common.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://www.tinymce.com/css/docs.min.css'>

    <style>
      body {
        background: transparent;  
      }

      .content {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
        min-height: auto;
        padding: inherit;
      }    
    </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <h2 class="editable">Editable header</h2>

    <div><p>Just more text</p></div>

    <script src='http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      tinymce.init({
        selector: 'h2.editable',
        inline: true,
        toolbar: 'undo redo',
        menubar: false
      });

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show some of your code to put it in context?

Comment: what floating panel?

Comment: if you run the code snippet and klick on the "editable header" the online editor with the floating panel appears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: The Question is very specific to tinymce! I checked if there is any class, id CSS styling on the floating panel, but i didn't found any, it seems the panel is styled in the code from tinymce (the inspected position is absolute and all CSS values are directly assigned to the DIV containing the Panel). I also checked the documentation about tinymce the whole section about the floating Panel, but i didn't found an option to align the Panel by an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setting `fixed_toolbar_container` to specify a CSS selector of an element that the toolbar will be placed in. Then you can position that container wherever you want.

This isn't the way it's done in the demo, but it should do what you want.

Here's a minimal example, which places the toolbar right-aligned immediately above the editor:

```
<style>
    .toolbar-wrapper { position: relative; }
    .toolbar { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
</style>
<div class="toolbar-wrapper">
    <div class="toolbar"></div>
</div>
<div class="editable">testing 1 2 3</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".editable",
        inline: true,
        fixed_toolbar_container: ".toolbar"
    });
</script>
```